# Unhandled Exception: A ChangeNotifier was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm getting this error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: A ModeManager was used after being disposed.
```

I'm using **ChangeNotifier** (class **ModeManager**) together with **ChangeNotifierProvider**.
Build method, where I create Provider looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !_isLoaded ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => ModeManager(_appUser),
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Connect Spotify'),
            ),
            body: AddSpotifyScreenBody(),
        ),
    );
}
```

Widget where I use provider looks something like this:

```
class _AddSpotifyScreenBodyState extends State<AddSpotifyScreenBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<ModeManager>(context);
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(provider.isCollecting ? 'COLLECTING NOW' : 'SHARING NOW'),
            //...some other widgets using provider...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anybody know what could cause this error or what am I doing wrong? Thank You very much.

Comment: Restart the app and see if it works or not. Also, check provider properly initialized or not

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It seems that you call `notifyListeners()` after disposing the widget with the `ChangeNotifierProvider()` .
This happened with me when a Future function call `notifyListeners()`. As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/sXEKZymSVeQ), you can override the `notifyListeners` method in the `ChangeNotifier` class :

```
@override
void dispose() {
  _disposed = true;
  super.dispose();
}

@override
void notifyListeners() {
  if (!_disposed) {
    super.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

don't forget to declare the variable `bool _disposed = false;`

Comment: Any idea how one could go about debugging this if `dispose()` is never called on the ChangeNotifier? At least the `print` statement in there never prints.

Comment: @BrunoEly , Check if the ChangeNotifier is declared as a global provider or it's ChangeNotifierProvider is still in the widget tree

Comment: You can also use safe_change_notifier from Canonical if you don't want to do this override yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Created an extension for `ChangeNotifier` based on @ismaeel Sherif's answer. If you are using classes extends `ChangeNotifier` in multiple places, its safe to use an extension like this.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisposeSafeChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _disposed = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    if (!_disposed) {
      super.notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

extend your class with `DisposeSafeChangeNotifier` instead of `ChangeNotifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Override dispose() in Widget cancel whatever work performFetch and expensiveOperation are doing, so that performFetch never actually calls notifyListeners.

You don't need to remove the listener before calling dispose, dispose clears the listener list.