# How can ChangeNotifierProvider be disposed in a healthy way?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

Note: Due to the structure we have set up, the ChangeNotifierProvider object needs to be generated more than once.
Object will be generated while generating the page, and disposed when the page is disposed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const MyHomePage(),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 void dispose() {
   // TODO: implement dispose
   super.dispose();

 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (context) => ViewModel(),
     child: SonrakiSayfa(),
   );
 }
}

class SonrakiSayfa extends StatelessWidget {
 const SonrakiSayfa({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var provider = Provider.of<ViewModel>(context);
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       actions: [
         IconButton(
           onPressed: () {
             /*When My Home Page is generated a few times with this button and the floating action button is pressed and returned immediately, I expect apiresponse to stop in the viewmodel.
*/
             Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
               ),
             );
           },
           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined),
         ),
       ],
     ),
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       onPressed: () {
         provider.fonksiyon();
       },
     ),
     body: Center(
       child: provider.apiResponse.status==Status.completed?Text(provider.apiResponse.data):CircularProgressIndicator(),
     ),
   );
 }
}

class ViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
 ApiResponse<String> _apiResponse = ApiResponse.initial("initial");

 ApiResponse<String> get apiResponse => _apiResponse;

 set apiResponse(ApiResponse<String> value) {
   _apiResponse = value;
   notifyListeners();
 }

 Future<void> fonksiyon() async {
   Future.delayed(
     const Duration(seconds: 5),
     () {
       apiResponse = ApiResponse.completed("Tamamlandı");
     },
   );
 }
}

class ApiResponse<T> {
 late Status status;
 late T data;
 late String message;

 ApiResponse.initial(this.message) : status = Status.initial;

 ApiResponse.loading(this.message) : status = Status.loading;

 ApiResponse.completed(this.data) : status = Status.completed;

 ApiResponse.error(this.message) : status = Status.error;

 @override
 String toString() {
   return "Status : $status \n Message : $message \n Data : $data";
 }
}

enum Status { loading, completed, error, initial }
```

The error I get is below

```
E/flutter (11012): \[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)\] Unhandled Exception: A ViewModel was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (11012): Once you have called dispose() on a ViewModel, it can no longer be used.
E/flutter (11012): #0      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed.\<anonymous closure\> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:147:9)
E/flutter (11012): #1      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:154:6)
E/flutter (11012): #2      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:330:27)
E/flutter (11012): #3      ViewModel.apiResponse= (package:untitled2/main.dart:92:5)
E/flutter (11012): #4      ViewModel.fonksiyon.\<anonymous closure\> (package:untitled2/main.dart:99:9)
E/flutter (11012): #5      new Future.delayed.\<anonymous closure\> (dart:async/future.dart:424:39)
E/flutter (11012): #6      Timer.\_createTimer.\<anonymous closure\> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (11012): #7      \_Timer.\_runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (11012): #8      \_Timer.\_handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (11012): #9      \_RawReceivePortImpl.\_handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (11012):
```

Comment: This answer should help you to get rid of that error https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842765/17104517 . For more details about what the `dispose`method does in `ChangeNotifier` class you can read here https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/sXEKZymSVeQ