# dispose a ChangeNotificationProvider within a StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dispose, flutter-provider

I have this nice exception `A TabClickNotifier was used after being disposed.`. The general answer is probably given here: [Unhandled Exception: A ChangeNotifier was used after being disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884633/unhandled-exception-a-changenotifier-was-used-after-being-disposed)

However, I have placed my `ChangeNotifierProvider` up in the widget tree, inside of a `StatelessWidget`.

```dart
class TaskEditPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskEditPage({super.key});

  static Route<void> route(String propertyId, String? taskId) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      fullscreenDialog: true,
      builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(create: (_) => TaskEditBloc(
            storePropertyTaskUC: StorePropertyTaskUC(),
            getPropertyTasksUC: GetPropertyTasksUC(context.read<PropertyRepository>()),
            propertyId: propertyId,
            taskId: taskId)..add(TaskEditRequested())),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TabClickNotifier())
          ],
        child: const TaskEditPage(),
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const TaskEditView();
  }
}
```

So how would I dispose the notifier in this case? I do not want to move the `ChangeNotifierProvider` further up in the tree, because it is used only every once in a while when an editing feature is used.

Any ideas?